# How To include external httpd.conf in Apache configuration based on Environment Variable

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'd like to include one or another external httpd.conf file in my main Apache httpd.conf based on an Environment Variable that is set externally.

So I would like to do something like:

`if $(DEV_ENV) == "main"

Include "first file"

if $(DEV_ENV) == "alt"

Include "second file"`

I've been looking at the mod_setenv module but that is for setting the environment variables within the Apache configuration.
How can I use the environment variables and do comparisons on its values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but you can't do this sort of dynamic logic on Includes.  However certainly the Debian version allows direct reference to environment variables through a substitution pattern, e.g.

```
Include conf/${APACHE_RUNTIME_TYPE}/*.conf
```

Have a browse for "Apache2 envvars" to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ifdefine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#ifdefine). This evaluates options passed on the command line, rather than environment variables. The following matches your request:

```
<IfDefine main>
Include "first file"
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine alt>
Include "second file"
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: "evaluates options passed on the command line" - Starting in Apache 2.4 you can now [`Define`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define) "variables" in the Apache config (as well as variables defined on the command line with the `-D` flag).